# ServiceMix NMR + Camel Route

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I use a ServiceMix + Camel combo for integration purposes.

Two of my camel routes uses the NMR component to exchange messages.
At startup I got the following exception if message were waiting to be processed:

```
ServiceMixException: Could not dispatch exchange. No matching endpoints.
```

I seems to be looking for a endpoint called `xyz:enpoint_name` which is created a few seconds later

```
18:48:44,266 | INFO  | xtenderThread-10 | ManagementEndpointRegistry       | ement.ManagementEndpointRegistry  129 | 88 - org.apache.servicemix.nmr.management - 1.3.0.fuse-02-00 | Registering endpoint: org.apache.servicemix.nmr.core.InternalEndpointWrapper@e6810f84 with properties {CHANNEL_SYNC_DELIVERY=false, NAME=xyz:enpoint_name}
```

- Is that expected ?
- Is there a way to prevent the route to start before all the endpoint have been initialized ?

Comment: are your routes in separate bundles?

Comment: That's right. Apparently, a consumer must be active on the NMR endpoint in order to avoid those errors. The wordaround I found until now is to start the bundles so that the consumer starts before the producer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use a [route policy](http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html) to control the startup/shutdown of routes, perhaps add a policy to check for the dependent route consumer prior to starting, etc...